# Merging tables from two Access databases into one new common

Tags: ms-access, vba, merge

I have this assignment that I think someone should be able to help me. I have 5 **ACCESS** databases wvrapnaoh.accdb, wvrappaul.accdb, ....etc. These databases have about 45 tables each and 15 forms. The good part is the structure, the name and the fields of each table in all the databases are all the same except the data or the records are different. For example I have a stress table in wvrapnoah as well as wvrappaul with the same fields in both tables but different data or records.

So, I need to merge all these five into a new Access database that will have the same structure as the 5 databases but will include the complete data that is all the records from the 5 databases  merged into this new database.The same applies to even the 15 forms. It does not seem to be having a primary key I guess. I was planning to add a field for each table that would give me the name of the database as well from which it was merged. Example I will add a DBName field in Wvrapnoah in all the tables and add the name Noah in that field for all the records in each table. I basically need to automate this code.

I need a script (VBA or anything) so that the guys creating these databases can just run this script the next time and merge the databases.

Comment: I think you are asking quite a lot. The general idea, AFAIK, is that you post some code and say what problems you have and people tell you how to fix the problems. You can also search SO for information, eg, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644930/merge-msaccess-tables

Comment: Yeah, this is Stackoverflow, not Rent-A-Coder.  Some code showing that you attempted this and failed somehow might be a good start.

Comment: Sounds as if this was rather a task for a database server anyway, with Access as the frontend. And you should re-think the whole databases structure, make it one database with a main table and the information you need to combine in related tables. Would be simple JOINs then, in a reasonable and relational database structure, clicked together easily in the Access query window.

Comment: I am casting a close vote because this obviously "needs more focus".

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the 'table' part of the problem:

Questions

- Are the databases / table names defined or you don't know them?
- Are you able to use linked tables?

I believe the straightforward way to merge all of them is to link all tables into a single access DB and then run a UNION ALL query. It would be something like this:

```
SELECT "HANK", *
FROM MyTableHank
UNION ALL
SELECT "JOHN", *
FROM MyTableJohn;
```

Notice I defined a field to identify the origin of the data being merged ("HANK", "JOHN"), as you suggested above.

About the forms, I believe you'll need to import them and then review the whole code. It basically depends on what the forms are doing. If they're query-based won't be a big deal (importing / fixing the queries, will make the form works). However, if the forms are related to the tables, you'll have more work to do.

Comment: UNIONs are inherently a performance drain unless you can use UNION ALL and you don't care about the ORDER BY of the overall set. The reason why is that UNIONs can't use the indexes for ordering (though it uses them for de-duping, at least for the fields in the SELECT that have indexes).

Comment: He will do this once to merge his DB's, Is performance really an issue here?

Comment: It's not necessarily a good solution to UNION, since there could be collisions (e.g., an Autonumber PK). Also, there might be relational issues that would require handling maintaining relations between the source data sets using new PK/FK values. So, I don't see that UNION would necessarily help, as you'd likely need to distinguish the data (though, of course, if you're inserting information into your new table that indicates the source, that can be supplied in the individual SELECT statements within the UNION).